# Sync 30G among several computers using different gmail accounts

Tags: sync, gmail, cloud-storage

I would like to sync my files between computers.

With gmail one has potentially 8G, and sometimes one can have several gmail accounts. I wonder if somehow several gmail accounts storage space could be used to sync for instance 30G between computers.

Preferably for free and for linux/mac

Comment: A Dropbox "Pro 50" account can store 50 GB. Currently $9.99/month.

Comment: Is this strictly email? I assume not given the size.  If so I have some tools in mind, if not a combo of rsync and gmailfs (mentioned below) would be my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Windows Live Mesh (if you are using Windows)

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other

"With Windows Live Mesh, you can sync up to 200 folders, each up to 50 GB in size and containing up to 100,000 files. "

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried any myself but there are people that use gmail as a filesystem.

Here is one implementation [gmailfs/](http://sr71.net/projects/gmailfs/)